# reset style oneach

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Using Leaflet with JavaScript I have a map with several GeoJSON Polygon layers.

```
var assembly = L.geoJSON(null, {onEachFeature: forEachFeature2, style: style2});  
$.getJSON(url2, function(data) {
    assembly.addData(data);
});
```

I use the onEachFeature's click event to highlight a polygon yellow when clicked. I currently have the layer name with a setStyle(style2) function before the highlight event to clear/reset the previous polygon's style.  So I only get one yellow polygon per click and they don't accumulate. While this works I have several layers so each layer has to have it's own onEachFeature function. I'd like to be able to set this layername by code, and have only one onEachFeature function.

```
function forEachFeature2(feature, layer) {
    layer.on("click", function (e) { 

        assembly.setStyle(style2);  //<<< layername is assembly
        layer.setStyle(highlight);
```

layer.SetStyle(style2) doesn't work.

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to bind your `"click"` event listener on the GeoJSON layer group, rather than on each individual child feature layer.

That way, `e.target` gives you access to the group (so that you can reset the style of that group rather than others), and `e.layer` gives you the individual child feature layer (so that you can highlight it in particular).

```js
assembly.on("click", onFeatureGroupClick);

function onFeatureGroupClick(e) {
  var group = e.target,
      layer = e.layer;

  group.setStyle(style2);
  layer.setStyle(highlight);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/quu3ykp6/8/